# pass context to lync client without using Conversation Window Extension

Tags: ucma

I want to pass context of the user to another lync client , so that based on the information passed the lync user will do some operation.I read through mail articles and found it is possible using ucma conversation context channel .But using this approach we have to implement Conversation Window Extension .Which I don't want to implement.

Please suggest without using Conversation Window Extension  ,How can I pass the context.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use the subject field.

In our project we have a custom Lync client (UI suppressed) and then the context channels does unfortunately not work so we use the subject field for custom data.

The subject is a string and I think it is limited to something like 1024 characters.